# What is wrong in this GBM simulation?

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

I am trying to generate a few samples of [GBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) using the following very simple MATLAB code:

```
function results=gbm(mean,vol,s0,T,shocks)
results = s0 * exp( (mean - vol^2/2) * T + vol^2 * sqrt(T) * shocks);
```

As you can see, I am using directly the closed form solution of the wiki page.

The thing is, I know that techincally $\mathbb{E}(S_t) = S_0 \exp(\mu t)$, but when I do:

```
 mean(gbm(0,.1,100,1,randn(1000,1)))
```

I get `99.54` as a result. How can that be?

I mean in the code above, I use $\mu=0$, so I'm expecting $\mathbb{E}(S_t) = S_0 \exp(0 )=S_0$

I've been looking at this too much and there might be something obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: you should plot that in time, probably will help.second, 99.54 is very close to S(0) = 100, so maybe it need more samples to converge

Comment: @Svisstack what do you mean plot in time? No even if I use 100'000 runs it stays close to `99.5`. I don't get it.

Comment: Simply: `exp(-0.1^2/2) = 0.9950125`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I agree, but still I don't get what is wrong with the implementation VS theoretical result $\mathbb{E}(S_t)=S_0$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typo "**vol^2**", but it should be "***vol***".

Its $$\sqrt{\sigma^2T}=\sigma\sqrt{T}$$

Comment: Oh thanks how did I miss that. I could have look 10 more hours at this...